# How to Trigger a Mutation, react + Apollo 2.1

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a mutation that is triggered when a button is clicked and returns a result. Now i would love to trigger another Mutation when that result is received and use that result in the next mutation.

so basically..

1. on click, call mutation.
2. mutation yields result.
3. collect result.
4. on result collected, trigger another mutation using that result.

Any Examples in this regard will go a long way to help.

This is what i have so far

```
_renderSubmitButton = () => {
const { firstName, lastName, email, dateOfBirth, phone } = this.state.fields;
const { isSaving } = this.state
return (

  <Mutation
    mutation={CREATE_PERSON_MUTATION}
    refetchQueries={() => [{ query: PERSON_QUERY }]}
    onCompleted={this._handleServerResponse}
    onError={this._handleServerError}
  >
    {
      (createPerson, { loading, data, error } ) => {   return (

          <Button
            primary
            disabled={!(firstName && lastName && dateOfBirth && email && !_.isEmpty(phone.number) && !_.isEmpty(phone.type))}
            onClick={() => this._submit({ createPerson, data, error, loading })}
            loading={this.state.isSaving}
          >
            Save <Icon name='right chevron' style={style.iconPad} />

          </Button>
        )
      }
    }
  </Mutation>
)
}

    _submit = async ({ createPerson, data, error, loading }) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ isSaving: true }));

    const person = this._buildPersonData();

    createPerson({ variables: { person } })
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.data.createPerson.personID);
      if(resp.data.createPerson.personID){
        this.setState({
          gottenID: true,
          accessID: resp.data.createPerson.personID
        });
      }

    })
   //TRIGGER ANOTHER MUTATION
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either concatenate or compose them, check [this library](https://github.com/jamesplease/react-composer) out!

Actually, composing them, you could do something like this:

```
const handleClick = async (mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn) => {
  const data1 = await mutation1Fn()
  const data2 = await mutation2Fn()
}

const Mutations = () => (
  <Composer
    components={[
      <Mutation mutation={mutation1} />,
      <Mutation mutation={mutation2} />
    ]}
  >
    {([mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn]) => (
      <button
        onClick={() => handleClick(mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn)}
      >
        exec!
      </button>
    )}
  </Composer>
)
```

Let me know if you're struggling with something!

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. This is awesome. I will try this now @carlos-rufo and get back to you